# I'm getting TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I'm trying to connect to an FTP server using sockets. I'm learning network programming so I'm not trying to use ftplib. I've searched all over stackoverflow because there are similar questions and I've tried everything solution stack users have to offer, but none of them have worked thus far. Any ideas what's going on?

```
def connect_to_target(username, password):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((target, 21))
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode()
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    s.send('PASS' + password + '\r\n').encode()
    data = s.recv(3).decode()
    s.send('QUIT\r\n')
    s.close()
    return data
```

The interpreter is saying that the problem is at line 13 which is

```
s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode().
```

I've tried a different variation like:

```
s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n'.encode())
```

When I tried the latter, it gives me:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

Comment: perhaps `s.send(('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode())`?

Comment: or `s.send('USER{}\r\n'.format(username).encode())`

Comment: @ace That worked, thank you! But I'm curious, do you have any idea why s.send(('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode()) works instead of s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n'.encode())?

Comment: @ace Wait, is it that .encode in s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n'.encode()) is only encoding the last part '\r\n' instead of the whole string, which is why the parenthesis version worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s.send()` expects an encoded byte stream to be the argument. So you want something like `s.send(str.encode())`.

When you do

```
s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode()
```

You are not encoding the string, you are encoding the return value of `s.send()`. It reads like `s.send(str).encode()`, which is not what you want.

Your second attempt is closer to what we should have, but in this case you haven't taken care of operator precedence.

```
s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n'.encode())
```

This is the same as first doing `'\r\n'.encode()`, then concatenating a string (`username`) with a bytes object (`'\r\n'.encode()`) which is not allowed. This expression has the form `s.send(str2 + str.encode())`, with the `.` operator having a higher precedence than the `+` operator, like how in math you have multiplication first before addition.

You want the *entire* string to be encoded. The way you did it only encodes the `'\r\n'` part of the string.

So you need to surround the string concatenation with parentheses, so that the concatenation will be performed first, before encoding it. So you need the following:

```
s.send(('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode())
#      ^                          ^ notice the parentheses here
```

Which is the form `s.send(str.encode())` we expected earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For this line

```
s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n').encode()
```

You are calling `encode` like it is a method of whatever is returned from `s.send`, this probably isn't what you intended.

For this line

```
s.send('USER' + username + '\r\n'.encode())
```

You are only calling encode on the final string in the sequence

```
'\r\n'.encode()
```

The resultant concatenation won't work because one of the strings was encoded (to `bytes` type) and the others were still normal `str` types.

To make it work you need to create a string of the whole lot and `encode` that.

```
s.send('USER{}\r\n'.format(username).encode())
```

Will do it without creating any temporary strings due to the `+` operator.